# How to run the same project version from windows and ubuntu in my apache localhost

Tags: windows, apache, ubuntu, localhost

This is for pure curiosity and power control.

I have a project on my localhost in ubuntu (or in windows). Now I want it to run on http://localhost/myproject on both Operating systems. The same version of the project as in edits while using any of the operating systems will effect the project and you can see the results on any of them.

Is that possible ?

Take Wordpress project as an example ( PHP Project )

Comment: What kind of project? Static HTML, PHP, ASP.NET, Rails?

Comment: PHP project like wordpress for example

Comment: I still don't understand your question. It is usually possible to run a PHP script on either platform - is that what you want to do?

Comment: No @pekka  i already have apache configured on both OS .. the idea is having the exact same script running on both localhosts and the edits i do from any of the OSs reflect on the same project .. where i can see and edit anywhere ! I hope this gets it a bit clearer

Comment: @mshestawy see Colin's answer, I think it sums it up pretty well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way of doing this is to put your php scripts into a shared directory, configure both webservers to point to that, and point it to a single shared database.

The right way of doing this is to use version control, continuous integration and automated deployment scripts.  Then when you check in your code, you can have it automatically roll out to all platforms you wish to test on.  I would recommend that you copy your database to each server too rather than connect multiple instances the same database.

I'd question why you want to bother with this at all though - Wordpress is pure PHP/MySQL and runs unchanged on a lot more platforms than just Windows and GNU/Linux.

---

EDIT: If you're determined to go down the quick and dirty route and you already have your php scripts on the Windows box, just mount your Windows share on Ubuntu, i.e.

```
mount -t smbfs //windowsbox/webroot /mnt/windows
```

(plus username/password etc as required)

Then use [the `Alias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) in Apache

```
Alias /wordpress /mnt/windows/wordpress 
Alias /myphpstuff /mnt/windows/myphpstuff
```

Then set up your MySQL so it's listening externally on the Windows box and configure Wordpress to connect to the external hostname of the Windows box (i.e. mycomputername not localhost)

Comment: First . thanks for the answer. and about wordpress .. it's just an example .. and obviously it wasn't a very good one :) .... however as I said up in the question description. this is for pure curiosity and power control. But I believe I may use it in the soon future.

Comment: Using SVN is pretty smart way of doing it . But I was hoping there is a simpler way of having a shared directory between ubuntu and windows and direct this to both localhosts, if that's possible !

Comment: @msheshtawy I have added more detail on the quick and dirty method using a shared directory.

Comment: Awesome ... Ill definitely try this one